# Peavey Vypyr 2 (40W) and sanpera 1

Tags: amplifiers

I have purchased a Sanpera 1 pedal unit and have been given a Peavey VYPYR 2 amp to use with it. I don't need all the sounds that the VYPYR produces, as having started playing in the 1950's and not keeping pace with the electronics over the years. I only need a "standard" amp. Can I use the Sanpera 1 with a simple standard amp? Thank you.